# UIAutomation: Any way to dismiss "Would Like To Use Your Current Location" alert?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, instruments, ios-ui-automation

my app is using location services, and for automated testing, I want to be able to dismiss the "APP Would Like To Use Your Current Location" popup. However, when I try to do this in Instruments with a UIAutomation script, I get this error:

```
Fail: Could not start script, target application is not frontmost.
```

This kind of makes sense, because the alert is produced by a different process. But still, what is Apple's plan for helping people automate their tests in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
**Try**

UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert)
        {
        return true;
        }
alertTitle = target.frontMostApp().alert().name();
if(alertTitle==="APP Would Like To Use Your Current Location")
{
target.frontMostApp().alert().buttons()["OK"].tap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be to use AppleScript, run after a sufficient delay to allow for the alert to appear. You tell it to click on the alert button in the window of the Simulator.

Comment: can you post your solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code before you trigger the appearance of the Location request dialog. Note the special quotation marks around the app name.

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert)
{
    if( alert.name()=="“local” Would Like to Use Your Current Location" )
    {
        alert.buttons()["OK"].tap();
    }
    else
    {
        UIALogger.logFail( "Location request dialog expected.");
    }
    return true;
}
```